# PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception Failed to load .... as a DOM document

Tags: laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

When I try to export datas as excel file on the specific request I got below error

> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception
> Failed to load path_to_project\storage\framework\laravel-excel\laravel-excel-pz23rYwVENIOZUw7vnvhKaNjUkkNLNT8.html as a DOM Document

I search alot but couldnot find any answer, the problem comes only when `semester = First Sem` but when semester is second, third etc this error doesn't come and I can download excel.

Below are my code

```
Route::get('/export', function () {
  return Excel::download(new ReportExport(request()->exams, request()->course, request()->semesterName), ''.request()->course.' '.request()->semesterName.'('.request()->exams.').xlsx');
})

// ReportExcel.php
$data = Fee::with(['backpapers' => function($bp) use ($myCourse, $semName) {
            $bp->where('course_name', $myCourse)->where('semester', $semName);
        }])->get();

 $table = '<table class="table table-border table-hover"><thead><tr><th>#</th><th>Roll No</th><th>Name</th><th>Reg_No</th><th>Father\'s Name</th><th>Gender</th><th>Aadhaar No</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Email</th><th>Paper 1</th><th>Paper 2</th><th>Paper 3</th><th>Paper 4</th><th>Exam Fee</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

 $count = 1;
 foreach ($data as $key => $bp) {
  if (count($bp->backpapers) > 0) {
    $table .= '<tr><td>'.$count.'</td><td>'.$bp->roll_number.'</td><td>'.$bp->name.'</td><td>'.($bp->registration_number != null ? $bp->registration_number : '-').'</td><td>'.$bp->father_name.'</td><td>'.($bp->gender == 1 ? 'Male' : 'Female').'</td><td>'.($bp->aadhaar_number != null ? $bp->aadhaar_number : '-').'</td><td>'.$bp->mobile_number.'</td><td>'.($bp->email != null ? $bp->email : '-').'</td>';
    
    $paperFee = BackpaperFee::where('number_of_paper', count($bp->backpapers))->pluck('fee_amount')->first();
    if (count($bp->backpapers) == 4) {
        foreach ($bp->backpapers as $bpp) {
            $table .= '<td>'.$bpp->paper_name.'</td>';
        }
    } elseif (count($bp->backpapers) == 3) {
        foreach ($bp->backpapers as $bpp) {
            $table .= '<td>'.$bpp->paper_name.'</td>';
        }
        $table .= '<td>-</td>';
    } elseif (count($bp->backpapers) == 2) {
        foreach ($bp->backpapers as $bpp) {
            $table .= '<td>'.$bpp->paper_name.'</td>';
        }
        $table .= '<td>-</td><td>-</td>';
    } elseif (count($bp->backpapers) == 1) {
        foreach ($bp->backpapers as $bpp) {
            $table .= '<td>'.$bpp->paper_name.'</td>';
        }
        $table .= '<td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>';
    }

    $table .= '<td>'.$paperFee.'</td></tr>';
    $count++;
  }
 }
 $table .= '</tbody></table>';
 
 return view('excel', compact('table'));
```

Like I said earlier, the error occurs when `semester=First Sem` only.

I tried:

1. `php artisan cache:clear`
2. `php artisan route:clear`
3. `php artisan view:clear`
4. `php artisan config:clear`

But nothing works.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Remove unwanted attributes from html element.
In my case i removed

```
 <table id="employee" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display table table-bordered" id="hidden-table-info">
```

and added `<table>` got fixed the issue

Answer (score 4):

Also!
Check your texts for symbols like ">" and "<" and change them with entities names:

```
&gt;
&lt;
```

Comment: also "&" for me

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 3):

For me, Error occurred because of `&`

First, it was `<td><b>Created & Published </b></td>` so it was generating an error.

So I changed it to `<td><b>Created and Published </b></td>` and it is resolved.

If you have "`&`" in your label or in values in loop, It may cause an error

Comment: You can replace & with `&amp;` to still show the & sign

Answer (score 1):

The Issue was that there was a Closing Anchor Tag, that was making the issue because while generating the Excel there must be no extra things or missing only Pure HTML table works for excel file generation nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Mine was I have an extra .

Delete it, and now its working again

Answer (score 0):

I have a button tag in my view which is the reference view file for export.

What I did was, I created another view file then copied the html format of the first view file reference. I deleted the button tag.

Then it works fine now.