# How to export excel after filter in laravel?

Tags: excel, laravel

I want to export only filtered data in view blade. I am using Laravel 7 and maatwebsite/excel 3.1 and PHP 7.4.2.

I went through the documentation and applied this:

View

```
<a href="{!! route('users.export-filter') !!}" class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="la la-download"></i>
    Export Filter
</a>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/users/export-filter', 'Admin\UserController@filter')->name('users.export-filter');
```

UserController.php

```
public function filter()
{
    return Excel::download(new FilterUserExport, 'filter.xlsx');
}
```

FilterUserExport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use Modules\User\Entities\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class FilterUserExport implements FromView, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{
    /**
     * @return View
     */
    public function view(): View
    {
        $users = app(User::class)->newQuery();

        if ( request()->has('search') && !empty(request()->get('search')) ) {
            $search = request()->query('search');
            $users->where(function ($query) use($search) {
                $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                    ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                    ->orWhere('mobile', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
            });
        }
        return view('users.index', compact('users'));
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->setRightToLeft(true);
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

export.blade.php

```
<table>
    <thead style="background-color: green; color: skyblue; border: 3px solid #ee00ee">
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>mobile</th>
        <th>national_id</th>
        <th>full_description</th>
        <th>thumbnai</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->mobile }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->national_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->full_description  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->thumbnailId  }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This code has not error but my problem did not solve yet

This code show all users but I want to show with filter.

The export submit button is sending everything to Excel. How do I make it to send only the filtered data. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636360/failed-to-load-excel-laravel-excel

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer my question?

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi could you check the output of `dd(request())` in your `view()` function.

Comment: @sykez I see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIl8y.png

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi I see. Could you verify if `dd(request()->all());` is empty or not. I've a feeling it's empty, so your filter condition isn't triggered at all.

Comment: I see this `[]`...

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer my question?

Comment: As I suspected. You need to do your logic in your controller, then pass the data to your Export. I'll add my answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter isn't working because as you mentioned in the comments, the `request()->all()` returns empty. So you'll need to move your logic into your controller.

**UserController.php**

```
public function filter()
{
    $users = app(User::class)->newQuery();

    if ( request()->has('search') && !empty(request()->get('search')) ) {
        $search = request()->query('search');
        $users->where(function ($query) use($search) {
            $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('mobile', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
        });
    }

    return Excel::download(new FilterUserExport($users), 'filter.xlsx');
}
```

**FilterUserExport.php**

```
class FilterUserExport implements FromView, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{
    private $users;

    public function __construct($users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    /**
     * @return View
     */
    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('users.index', ['users' => $this->users]);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->setRightToLeft(true);
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

Basically I moved your logic from `view()` to the controller and passed the filtered `$users` to your *Export* class.